# how to comment/uncomment XAML code in vs2010 by keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I would like to know is there any keyboard shortcut available for xaml code comment and uncomment. I don't want to type all the time. is there any faster way to do it?

Answer (score 14):

**Comment**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

**Uncomment**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>